# How to follow questions with specific tags

Tags: support, tagging, rss

Is there a way to have the feed on math.stackexchange.com display only questions under specific tags? It would be nice to be able to follow questions one is potentially interested in and able to answer, without the need for third party RSS readers. I'd like for the feed to display more than one tag, and possibly for the tags to be saved on my account for quick access after every login. Maybe I'm missing an obvious way to do this, but I tried fiddling around in the "tags" section and I couldn't find anything. Thank you for your advice!

Comment: See also here: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3814/filtering-by-tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know two ways:

#### Tag search

Compose a tag query in the search box, separating the desired tags by `or`. For example, entering

> [abstract-algebra] or [group-theory] or [linear-algebra] or [ring-theory]

will lead to [this view](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abstract-algebra+or+group-theory+or+linear-algebra+or+ring-theory?sort=active&pageSize=50). Sort by either newest or active, as you prefer, and bookmark the link.

#### Filter

Go to [stackexchange.com/filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/) and create a filter. You can either enter tags manually, or just tell it to use the tags you chose as favorite. In the latter case, the tag will be automatically updated in the future if your set of favorite tags changes.

The easiest way to mark a tag as favorite is to hover over the tag name and click the star in the upper left corner of the hover-window. This toggles the tag between neutral, favorite, and ignored.

One drawback of the filter is that TeX does not render on the stackexchange.com site. But I think this is a mild inconvenience, which is partially compensated by faster rendering of the list of questions.

Comment: Between these, I choose: neither, I have a [better filter](http://dropproxy.com/f/7FC#interesting) for unanswered interesting questions.

Comment: Thanks! The filter option was exactly what I was looking for